# Transforming pseudocode with conditional statements into mathematical equation

Tags: if-statement, math, pseudocode

I am currently in the process of transforming my programming code into mathematical equations for my bachelor thesis.

My pseudocode looks like this:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    if X[i] < Y[i] then
         p += X[i] * k1 + (Y[i] - X[i]) * k2
    else
         p += Y[i] * k1
    endif
endfor
```

My attempt to convert the pseudocode into a mathematical equation:

[image: equation]

Would that be mathematically correct? Or are there more intuitive ways?

Comment: Your pseudocode has `range(0,n)` but your latex formula has `\sum_{i=1}^n`. There is at least one discrepancy about `i=0`. Maybe about `i=n` as well, although that depends on what it is you call `range(0,n)` (in python for example, that wouldn't include the `n`; in pseudocode, there's no way to know what you meant)

Comment: Other than that, the min/max logic is correct.

Comment: @Stef Thanks, do you think for a bachelor thesis in computer science it is ok to just use min/max in equation instead of the underlying quadratic formula?

Comment: I don't know what underlying quadratic formula you are talking about? Yes, min/max is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for your estimation. I am talking about these: [link](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/the-maximum-and-minimum-of-two-numbers-using-the-quadratic-formula)

Comment: Please do use min/max.

Comment: Note that in Python for numerical calculations it is handy to use numpy, and write your code as `p = np.sum(np.minimum(X, Y) * k1 + np.maximum(Y - X, 0) * k2))` which is much closer to the mathematical formulation. Making it easier to compare both (and making it run much faster).  (By the way, I think it is very adequate to have your indices in Python starting with 0 and in your mathematical formula with 1.)